# Vagrant up --provision giving error

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

This question might look like duplicate-ish but I was unable to find the exact issue anywhere with my best searching effort.

Everything was working fine till yesterday. Today I cannot get `vagrant up --provision` to work. The error I am getting is:

> The box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' could not be found or could not be
>   accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private box on
>   HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via `vagrant login`.
>   Also, please double-check the name. The expanded URL and error message
>   are shown below:
>
> URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bento/ubuntu-16.04"] Error: The
>   requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

I tried `$ vagrant login`. When I went to https://atlas.hashicorp.com, it only gives me the option to login, but I didn't see a way to sign up!

And surpringly https://hasicorp.com/ says its for sale!!

Please suggest how I can get rid of it!

Answer (score 1):

https://hasicorp.com/ is for sale but as long as https://www.hashicorp.com is working, I think you'll be fine.

Also the box `bento/ubuntu-16.04` is available for download on the vagrant cloud at https://app.vagrantup.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-16.04

1. Make sure you're using an up-to-date version of vagrant
2. Make sure the `metadata_url` file for this box points to vagrantup.com
   check `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/<your_box>/metadata_url` and edit them to use vagrantup.com

Comment: Thanks a lot! Updating to latest provisioned the box. One question though. Initially I had another site configured for vagrant box, but now after updating to latest and `vagrant up` a default site is appearing with `vagrant.local`. Do I need to reconfigure the previous site using Chassis and all?